# HP Triplets formula

Tags: elementary-number-theory

May be I miss something elementary, but what formula like

$$ \frac1p, \frac2{p+q}, \frac1q $$

generates three positive integers in a harmonic progression?

EDIT1:

So the question is :

It is required to find three positive integers in HP each of which is a function of two positive integers $m, n.$

Answer (score 1):

You could let $p=3$, $q=5$, and you will get
$$\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{5}$$
In order for that to be in harmonic progression, the denominators must be in arithmetic progression when the numerators are each $1$, so 
$$p, \frac{p+q}{2}, q$$
need to be in arithmetic progression. Then let $d$ be the common difference. Now we have that the following must be satisfied:
$$p+d=\frac{p+q}{2}$$
$$q-d=\frac{p+q}{2}$$
This implies that
$$p+d=q-d$$
and
$$p+2d=q$$
Now we see that if we choose any $p$ and $q$ such that $p+2d=q$, the arithmetic progression is satisfied:
$$p, \frac{p+q}{2}, q$$
$$p, \frac{p+p+2d}{2}, p+2d$$
$$p, \frac{2p+2d}{2}, p+2d$$
$$p, p+d, p+2d$$
And if the arithmetic progression of the denominators is satisfied when the numerators are each equal to $1$, then the sequence is harmonic.

TL,DR: Let $q=p+2d$, where $q, p$, and $d$ are real numbers.

Now you need to find when $\frac{1}{p}$, $\frac{1}{p+d}$, and $\frac{1}{p+2d}$ are all positive integers. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Sorry about it  I edited the question what I actually meant, my given example not so relevant..

Comment: Oh, I see. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: May be you can answer  ( 3 numbers from two integer symbols)